# macOS Big Sur: Handling APFS Time Machine backups with tmutil

Tags: macos, time-machine

Time Machine on Big Sur an APFS changed many things.

See https://eclecticlight.co/2021/03/25/time-machine-to-apfs-maintenance-and-repair/ for some information.

For the life of me, I cannot handle, compare and check those backups.

The backup device itself only shows the last backup, it seems:

```
mini:~ root# ls /Volumes/T5_1TB/
total 48
drwx------  4 _unknown  _unknown    128 Jul 31 17:15 .Spotlight-V100/
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 root      wheel       192 Sep  3 15:31 2021-09-03-153159.previous/
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root      wheel     20795 Sep  3 15:32 backup_manifest.plist
```

More of them are just mounted "local snapshots"

```
mini:~ root# mount | grep TimeMachine | wc -l
      48

mini:~ root# mount | grep TimeMachine | tail -1
com.apple.TimeMachine.2021-08-17-213011.backup@/dev/disk7s1 on /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-08-17-213011.backup (apfs, local, read-only, journaled, nobrowse)
```

tmutil can list the backups:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil listbackups | wc -l
      40
mini:~ root# tmutil listbackups | tail -1
2021-09-03-153159.backup
```

That number does not correspond to the mounted volumes, which is strange.

The "tmutil compare -s" command works ...

But I cannot find a way to do the following things:

1. See the size of the individual backups (solved, see below)
2. See the list of files that were backup'd, and their sizes in the backup:

   The /Volume/.timemachine/ snapshots each contain all files of the system, it seems.
   How to see which files were actually saved?
3. Delete selected backups

   While the command itself seems to work, I see no reduction in space used:

   ```
   mini:~ root# df -k /Volumes/T5_1TB/
   Filesystem   1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
   /dev/disk7s1   976557744 177325284 799030000    19% 1483217 9764094223    0%   /Volumes/T5_1TB

   mini:~ root# tmutil delete -d /Volumes/T5_1TB -t 2021-09-03-143154
   1 backups deleted

   mini:~ root# df -k /Volumes/T5_1TB/
   Filesystem   1024-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
   /dev/disk7s1   976557744 177278252 799077036    19% 1483217 9764094223    0%   /Volumes/T5_1TB
   ```

   No change at all.

---

I read websites since days, but Apple - as so often - does not document nothing, the man page just does not seem to be up-to-date and I cannot find any other website with current information.

This does also not work:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil calculatedrift /Volumes/T5_1TB/

Drift Averages
-------------------------------------
Added:         0B
Removed:       0B
Changed:       0B
```

While trying around, I found a working way to see the size of an individual backup - IF and WHEN it is mounted to /Volumes/.timemachine:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil uniquesize /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-153159.backup/2021-09-03-153159.backup/
1012.0K /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-153159.backup/2021-09-03-153159.backup

mini:~ root# tmutil uniquesize /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-133208.backup/2021-09-03-133208.backup/
63.4M /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-133208.backup/2021-09-03-133208.backup
```

But that still does not show, which files are contained ...
And how to do that, when the snapshot volumes are NOT mounted?
I cannot see any of them on the disk itself - as shown above, the is only one mountpoint visible ...

Everything is very cryptic.

Also, the latest backup is not normally mounted, it seems - so I cannot check it's size:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil listbackups | tail -1
2021-09-03-163148.backup

mini:~ root# tmutil latestbackup
2021-09-03-163148.backup

mini:~ root# ls -ald /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-163148.backup
ls: /Volumes/.timemachine/B65704A0-0BA8-4818-AB7B-2A9F9B1977C3/2021-09-03-163148.backup: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

BTW, I can create a new "localsnapshot", but it is completely unclean to me, what this means - it does not seem to change anything at all:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil localsnapshot
NOTE: local snapshots are considered purgeable and may be removed at any time by deleted(8).
Created local snapshot with date: 2021-09-03-164519

mini:~ root# tmutil latestbackup
2021-09-03-163148.backup

mini:~ root# mount | grep 2021-09-03-164519
mini:~ root#
```

What did that do?!?

This may be, because those localsnapshots are not part of APFS, but this is a guess from:

```
mini:~ root# tmutil listlocalsnapshots /Volumes/T5_1TB
/Volumes/T5_1TB is an APFS backup disk. Use 'tmutil listbackups' to list APFS backup snapshots.
```

Comment: This probably would have been better off getting migrated to https://apple.stackexchange.com/ but that is not an option...

Answer (score 1):

APFS is capable of creating a snapshot of the file system at any moment, which means any write operations after creating one go to different blocks on your disk, much like changes to a lightweight copied file.

When Time Machine starts a backup, it does a local snapshot, so anything you change during the backup won't be included. It then copies the content of that snapshot to your backup disk.

After that, the last local snapshots are kept until the space is needed for new data, which means you can access them even if your backup disk is not connected. When they get purged, you will need the backup disk to get your old files back.